# Laravel backend (API) routes and login page security

Tags: laravel, api, security

I am working on a back-end written in Laravel which also serves as an API. Few days back the API sends various spam emails to hundreds of users. Where as from stats report I came to know that LOGIN page of APP is also accessed multiple times but it is already protected with CSRF token. Do I need to implement any additional security on it like middle-ware on login page?

Moreover, do i need to secure all routes. If yes then how?

Thanks

Comment: How did you 'secure' the routes? Can you provide an example

Comment: The question is to broad. If you ask how you have been hacked then we don't know. If you ask how you want to protect yourself then please look into https://owasp.org/www-project-application-security-verification-standard/ and implement ALL level 1 requirements. See you in two years.

Comment: Well implement all standards is quite impossible. There should be some must steps to secure it and I believe that if I only implement them and it works.

Comment: @Collin: for login I am using Laravel auth. Example is: 
Auth::routes(); Moreover, some other url's are like that Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/product/{product}', 'ProductsController@show');
Route::get('/quote','QuoteController@index');
Hope this helps

Comment: I understand @EBDEV but i mean your custom routes. Are they protected by a auth middleware or just accesable at all times?

Comment: @Collin, no they are not protected by a middleware. Do I need to protect all links with middleware?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you question it seems that you use the authentication for logging in but you dont actually protect the routes.
This means that the login is redundant.
For protecting routes there are multiple options. THe simplest way to protect a route is:

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
    // place routes that require authentication in here. 
})->middleware('auth');
```

Another option is using the construct funciton in the controller.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

For more information on protecting routes take a look at the laravel documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Comment: Thanks let me check it. Moreover can I also implement Laravel Passport to secure my website?

Comment: You can,  i dont use it myself but you can implement it.

Comment: Do I also need to setup HTTPS on my server or not?

Comment: YES, always use https.